# Can a real image plane and a virtual object plane be same?

Tags: optics

For example, a real image plane can be calculated using a virtual object in a two convex lenses system. The real image of the first lens can be the virtual object so this can be used as the object of the second lens.

Is there any special case that the two planes are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with three lenses, but not with two unless the images are at infinity.  To find cases with  three lenses,  try using the lensmaker's equation for three lenses, re-written to refer to the location of each image relative to the source object on the axis of the system.  Set the first image position equal to the third image position. You will then have equations into which you can plug in reasonable values (positive and/or negative) for lens focal lengths, and which you can use to solve for the positions of the lenses.